# validar 2 recaptchas na memsa pagina por ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, validação, google, recaptcha

Fala galera blz ? estou precisando de um help
implementei na mesma  página 3 recaptchas.

```
<form id='form1'><div class="g-recaptcha" id="Login" data-sitekey="minhakey"></div></form>

<form id='form2'><div class="g-recaptcha" id="reset" data-sitekey="minhakey"></div></form>

<form id='form3'><div class="g-recaptcha" id="email" data-sitekey="minhakey"></div></form>
```

dai no meu arquivo js coloquei o seguinte cod.

```
var CaptchaCallback = function(){
    $('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
        grecaptcha.render(el, {'sitekey' : 'minhakey'});
    });
};
```

e por fim no rodapé

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer>
```

ate ai tudo bem.
ele gera a pagina com os 3 forms e os 3 reCAPTCHAS
o problema é na validação
quando utilizo o `grecaptcha.getResponse()`
ele só funciona para o primeiro recaptcha. para os outros 2 não funciona
dai achei no google que se eu uzar desta forma funcionaria

```
grecaptcha.getResponse(elementId);
```

então utilizei `var response = grecaptcha.getResponse(reset);`

so que ao fazer isso ao invés dele gravar na variavel response ele faz um request na minha pagina com a response e minha pagina atualiza com a url do meu site + o response

> http://meusite.com.br/?g-recaptcha-response=03AHJ_Vuuoeweb5zQIEXqdCkUqMm5lhbDqM4GP7k-CAbra-5Yl7CQvjb-IJRZOoiE_Cs2BbAsODSl4OdBTPqZcOVN6JTYjjagBLgPASJ9l-zgDhnKo1C3R6eAQIbzYHdcauT05mNyxuBfmw-9XW2e5l2LYLTz59ejc77bWtigD2zWhMnGxV5lwPyB28DAllF12az0ku171lOmxPltn_b7vAwSxSt9Nq43LfsmifTjrleXimpcxM6_ogRrkCA00tGnJAJVlk9LVXd28fgktXo47TDkJCQbPM2YVvE40s0QL9IBbeLBSUmmme8HPaQ4MzMeYYqConltTCbKV0MIk6GwofaUJH8xcuG2xi_iH36zZkTa41vR7Xy2_azCOU6UDA4L-SneOnkmbVoeX8_fb8Y9yMPzCZKobng3usLW8nWr0-ffodj8FENuKrMzYd9LuonTs30eRBqN-EM1ZqfVsS0k-egD6tB89GXLctLhzNOWtC7GbjH7YoCWd1lt9BK_UlSgfnEW27zF0UuRngLoKQVXQVEO5WO40oqkkRiTpWSeZeMCs_Rb5SO3iOOHLByJI4NvPcc3js9er9wq8Fvvo9_lM5KzDcl2vW6k86df-GZJrCJgcloIR3Z7QwhPY-MTCjn7bfYM4onF44AO3LMr0FVUeaC4H59NrF2Vt87nrDVqcP_jiFvbb6RfgQd7SSg1ERFS6kuXLgGDKjmO3amn2IO6GgGdlRl0kpm5ehT3tSaZ1B6EFHn9-Eoz1tTTY2DsNUl-s0JKEK0amDlHtAhwlmJH4Y6QoweWuAWjA0PI451PUtk3lHYqL6afjsWUy_54pLrVTY0q4Sozi90zSyfFYBe_qS1uI_pLixPlBzs38eAwgOeEk7PpF6jW69arIKKb5hLpCV9hoHcySkEUP0SFZz5JS2e5RYaa0aAwZbL_039vhDGtQsoPH4bL_Fd9H6e5bfINDJS7qTVRIQmLp

por gentileza alguém já enfrentou este problema ou alguém sabe como resolver?
agradeço dês de já;

eu fiz como vc disse:

```
var reLogin;
var reLost;
var reRegister;
var onloadCallback = function() {

    var reLogin = grecaptcha.render($('#reLogin')[0], {'sitekey' : '6LcZ-wsUAAAAAOkcUWs5OiVIQW6Td2aIYPf8aMxe'});
    var reLost = grecaptcha.render($('#reLost')[0], {'sitekey' : '6LcZ-wsUAAAAAOkcUWs5OiVIQW6Td2aIYPf8aMxe'});
    var reRegister = grecaptcha.render($('#reRegister')[0], {'sitekey' : '6LcZ-wsUAAAAAOkcUWs5OiVIQW6Td2aIYPf8aMxe'});
};
```

e na minha validação no onclick

```
alert(grecaptcha.getResponse(reLost));
```

só que o alert vem vasio.

Answer (score 1):

O `grecaptcha.getResponse(elementId)` espera uma referencia que o `grecaptcha.render(el, {'sitekey' : 'minhakey'})` retornou pra você, e não o id do DOM (`id='reset'`,  `id='email'`, etc).

Eu faria, pra cada um dos captchas:

```
var reset = grecaptcha.render($('#reset')[0], {'sitekey' : 'minhakey'})

grecaptcha.getResponse(reset);
```

No lugar do loop `.each` que você fez.

Comment: vou atualizar da uma olhada por favor.

Comment: Você tem que declarar o `var reLogin`, `var reLost` só fora da função, ao declarar novamente dentro da função, o JS cria outra variável com o mesmo nome, mas com escopo só dentro dela.

Comment: ainda não funcionou eu tirei da função onloadcallback e nada :*(

Comment: acho que vou fazer diferente em vez de manter todos formulários escondidos na pagina vou fazer carregar por ajax.

Comment: Deixa o recaptcha fora do lance de login/lost/register. Cria um só e mostra ele independente do que o usuário escolher.

Comment: ok vou tentar muito obrigado.